# Is it possible to get notification from Skype in my app iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, skype

I'm working on the Client app, and now Server app has already integrated the Skype API (C#), server app sends some messages to some Skype ID. I want to my Client app (installed on their iphone) also get this notification from skype. Is it possible to do that? Please give me some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: If you mean that your app should receive the push notification from Skype, **NO** this is not possible. Your only option is to find a iOS library for Skype.

Comment: @rckoenes: I mean when the phone receive the message in skype, is it possible to trigger my app to do something?

Answer (score 1):

Apple is very controlling when it comes to sandbox-ing applications. You application can not get Notifications from Skype. The only possibility would be if Skype gives out an API, using which you could get notifications. (Last I checked there wasn't any)

Comment: Thanks for your explaination